# Foro limite de votaciones por post PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, web

Buenas, estoy intentando hacer un foro en el que los usuarios registrados puedan escribir comentarios y valorar, el problema esta en que un usuario registrado puede valorar tantas veces como quiera y me gustaría que el usuario pudiera valorar 1 vez por comentario.

La página es http://radiohumorfm.com/comentario.php

El código ese el siguiente:

```
<script>

    function like(id) {
        if (id.length == 0) { 
            return;
        } else {
            window.location.href = "like.php?id="+id;
        }
    }

   function dislike(id) {
    if (id.length == 0) { 
        return;
    } else {
        window.location.href = "dislike.php?id="+id;
    }   
   }
    function deletecom(id)
    {
      if (id.length == 0) 
      {
         return;

      } else 
      {   

        alertify.confirm('Eliminar este comentario','¿Estas seguro que quieres eliminar este comentario?',
          function(){

            window.location.href = "deletecom.php?id="+id;
          },
          function(){
            alertify.error('Cancel');
          });
      }    
    }
    function añadir(){
        alertify.success('Ok');
    }

</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','password','radiohumorfm');
$comentarios = "SELECT * FROM comentarios ORDER BY id ASC";

if($listacomentarios = $conn->query($comentarios)){ 
while($filas = $listacomentarios->fetch_row()){

        echo ("<div class='col-md-8 col-md-offset-2'>");
        echo ("<div class='separador'></div>");
        echo("<div class='panel panel-info'>");
        echo("<div class='panel-heading'>");
        echo ("<strong>".$filas[1]."</strong>");

    echo("<span style='right:35px; position:absolute;'>");

     if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) { 



    echo("<i style='color:dodgerblue ; cursor:pointer'class='fa fa-thumbs-up fa-2x' aria-hidden='true' onclick='like(id=".$filas[0].")'></i>
    <i style='color:red; cursor:pointer'class='fa fa-thumbs-down fa-2x' aria-hidden='true' onclick='dislike(id=".$filas[0].")'></i>");

     }
    echo ("<strong>");
    echo $filas[4];
    echo ("</strong>");
    if ($_SESSION['usuario']=="admin"){
    echo("<i style='color:gray; cursor:pointer'class='fa fa-trash-o fa-2x' aria-hidden='true' onclick='deletecom(id=".$filas[0].")'></i>");
    }
        echo("</span>");

        echo ("</div>");
        echo ("<div class='panel-body'>");

        echo $filas[2];
        echo("<div class='fecha' align='right'>");
        echo $filas[3];
        echo ("</div>");
        echo ("</div>");
        echo ("</div>");
        echo ("</div>");
}
}                   
$conn->close();
```

PHP del archivo like:

```
`<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
$id = $_GET['id'];

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','patata','radiohumorfm');
$like = "update comentarios set puntuacion=puntuacion+1 where id='$id'";
$conn->query($like);
$conn->close();   
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
else{

    echo "Acceso no permitido";
}
?>`
```

Un Saludo y Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lo que tienes que hacer es almacenar en BBDD los votos del usuario y cada vez que recargues la pagina comprobar si ya ha votado a ese elemento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder controlar las votaciones de los usuario, debería crear una tabla en la Base de Datos en donde antes de que entre ha cambiar el voto primero valide si ese usuario ya ha votado antes, Ejemplo..

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
$id = $_GET['id'];

realiza una consulta  select * from controlvotantes where idusuario=$id

if(si el usuario esta no esta en la tabla controlvotantes){ 

$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','patata','radiohumorfm');
$like = "update comentarios set puntuacion=puntuacion+1 where id='$id'";
$conn->query($like);

insertar el usuario en la tabla controlvotantes 

insert into controlvotantes values ('$id')

ya si vuelve a votar el mismo usuario quedara en el primer filtro y no podra volver a votar 

$conn->close();   
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);

}else{

si el usuario ya esta en la tabla controlvotantes es por que ya voto una vez 

   echo "Ya se a relizado una votacion con su usuario ";

}
}
else{

    echo "Acceso no permitido";
}
```